# Search Array and get substring result

Tags: c#

I have a string array as follows:

```
string[] stringArray = { "1122|false", "1123|true", "1124|true", "1125|false" };
```

In essence, it is broken down by id|active where for example id is say 1122 and active is true or false.

Say my id was 1123, how would I search this array to get the value of true in this case? I understand Substring needs to be used with IndexOf but not sure how to tie it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Little bit of LINQ and String.Split should do the trick.

```
string[] stringArray = { "1122|false", "1123|true", "1124|true", "1125|false" };

int id = 1123;

var itemWithGivenId = stringArray
           .SingleOrDefault(s => int.Parse(s.Split('|')[0]) == id);
Console.WriteLine(bool.Parse(itemWithGivenId.Split('|')[1]));
```

Comment: he want's the "value of true", not the entire element.

Comment: @Andy It's pretty easy to use string.Split and retrieve the value.

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: @Nate Pat My pleasure.

Comment: @RazMegrelidze If you do not mind, can you update with string.Split. Does not seem to be working for me. Thank you

Comment: @NatePet i did. But you should probably make a method from this code for further use.